# "Official" syntax for referring to method of a class in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ruby, syntax

In Ruby, when referring to the "downcase" method of the class "String", I write String#downcase. When talking about the "new" class method, I write String.new.

Is there something similar for Objective-C?

Comment: Actually, the canonical way to refer to "class methods" (please note there is no such thing as a class method in Ruby, it's just a standard instance method on the class object's metaclass) is as `String::new`. The message sending notation is only used in examples, when referring to class instances. So, within the documentation of `String#downcase` there could be an example and within that example you would use `str.downcase`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given a class declaration like this

```
@interface MyClass (NSObject)
{}

+ (id)classMethod;
- (id)instanceMethod;
@end
```

it is common practice to refer to `classMethod` as `+[MyClass classMethod]` or more compactly `+classMethod` if the class is clear. Similarly, I would refer to `instanceMethod` as `-[MyClass instanceMethod]` or `-instanceMethod`.

Comment: Great answer, I always use the class name (the **+** or **-** disambiguates class and instance methods) and the shorthand form you mention (for methods in the same class, or when the class is clear) is quite useful. In addition, remember that for methods which accept one or more parameters, use the full selector name, including colons. For example, `+[NSString stringWithFormat:]`, `-[NSString initWithFormat:arguments:]`, etc.

Comment: Good answer.  When referring to a method in prose, I've always used the `(+|-)methodWithArgs:moreArgs:` way to make it clear which was intended.

Answer (score 5):

gdb uses `+[MyClass foo]` and `-[MyClass bar]`;

Answer (score -1):

If you are referring to a method like:

```
+ (void)someClassMethod;
```

on class MyObject then you would call it like this:

```
[MyObject someClassMethod];
```

Comment: Yes, I know how to call a method in Obj-C. What I mean is: how would you refer to a method in, say, documentation or comments, in a less verbose way than "the method someMethod of [the class] SomeClass".